# Update query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Run my Query and i got an error.. my query is written  below

```
$qry = "UPDATE Offer  SET offer_year='$offeryear', " .
"course_code='$coursecode', offer_list='$offerlist', " .
"WHERE offer_id ='$offerid'";
```

the error i got is

```
ERROR: Record could not be added
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE offer_id ='1'' at line 1
```

done some changes on my update query i still got an error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (you had a comma after `offerlist`):

```
$qry = "UPDATE Offer  SET offer_year='$offeryear', " .
"course_code='$coursecode', offer_list='$offerlist' " .
"WHERE offer_id ='$offerid'";
```

Answer (score 3):

If you try to check it one by one, you have extra `comma` before the `WHERE` clause

```
$qry = "UPDATE Offer  SET offer_year='$offeryear', " .
       "course_code='$coursecode', offer_list='$offerlist' ". // remove comma here
       "WHERE offer_id ='$offerid'";
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Update your update query like this

```
$qry = "UPDATE Offer  
        SET offer_year='$offeryear',
            course_code='$coursecode', 
            offer_list='$offerlist' 
        WHERE offer_id ='$offerid'";
```

You have put extra comma before WHERE condition